# How do I have 32 reviews in the low quality posts queue?

Tags: support, bug, review, low-quality-posts, limits

I noticed I somehow have 32 reviews today in the LQP queue on Stack Overflow:

[image]

Only after my 32nd review did I get the message that I'm only allowed 20 reviews. This is not a new problem, every day I reviewed this week I seemed to be able to do 22-25 out of 20 reviews, though this is my first time getting over 30.

My question is, is this a bug or intentional design? If intentional, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Taryn notes [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/208273):

> - When the queue size is greater than 150, you will have 40 reviews a day
> - When the queue size is less than 150, you will have 20 reviews a day

Being stopped at some number between 20 and 40 often happens when the queue size was greater than 150 earlier, but then drops below that number.

From your screenshot, the queue currently has fewer than 150 items, so you are unable to continue reviewing unless it grows to more than 150 items.

As with all things Stack Exchange, changes in review limit in response to items being added or removed may or may not be delayed slightly due to [caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/).